# Validating extra letter in encrypted text in php

Tags: php

Here is the method i am using encrypt and decrypt in php.

```
function ecrypt($str){
     $key = "ABCDEH";
     for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
          $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
          $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
          $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
          $result.=$char;
       }
    return base64_encode($result);
 }



 function decrypt($str){
    $str = base64_decode($str);
    $result = '';
    $key = "ABCDEH";
  for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
     $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
     $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
     $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
     $result.=$char;
  }
 return $result;
```

}

The encrypted text may contain name and expiry date.If my encrypted text is:

`1yUoaCToqmsqq+4unuFdXWJc4R5hnmL`

i will decrypt and will calculate the expiry date but the problem is if the user entered `1yUoaCToqmsqq+4unuFdXWJc4R5hnmLL`(i added extra one letter in end of the encrypted key).

If i decrypt it and check the expiry date, its also working.I should throw the error message in case of extra letters.

Please advice me.

Comment: You aren't doing an encryption. Thats just a little bit of character replacement. Why aren't you using an already included, proper cryptograpic PHP-function? Maybe you have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.mcrypt.php) Or you have a look at some related questions here in the sidebar.

Comment: Holy histories batman, we have a primitive vignere

Comment: You should verify that the input to `base64_decode()` is actually a string that has a length which is a multiple of 4.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789: So if I add just 4 additional characters as a user everything will be fine...

Comment: Store the encrypted value in database. When user entered value before decrypt compare the entered value with database and proceed

Comment: @oktopus Of course it would... in that stage. The decryption, however, wouldn't yield a valid result (which is the intended behavior... I assume). The problem here is that an extra 1 byte in the input results in an extra 0.75 bytes in the `base64_decode()`'d value -- and that fraction is discarded.

Comment: I just calculated the string length and divided by 4.If it correct the remainder value will be 0.Its working. Thank you so much !!!